# Why are my tests not triggering my filter?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I have following Problem. My tests are running allways positive even when the HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION headder has a wrong token. In theory it should fail because I have a filter that checks the token. 
My Jax-RS program is working perfectly in the browser or using a httpclient like postman. So I have to generate a token first and then use that token to run the HTTP commands otherwise it will return the statuscode 401. 
I think that my configuration is wrong and the Testframework is running the tests without triggering the filter.
I never worked with Jax-RS before and I have no Idea how to fix that...

```
public class GamesTest extends JerseyTest{


@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(Games.class).register(new AbstractBinder() {
        protected void configure() {
            bind(GamesXMLDB.class).to(MyGameDBInterfaceDB.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(UserXMLDB.class).to(MyUserInterfaceDB.class).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    });
}   


@Test
public void getWithoutTokenTest() {
    Response response = target("/games").request().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "").get();
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot I had to add the filter.class to the ResourceConfig. I thought this was not needed as it would find the filter via the annotation.

Comment: Can you add that how to do that mate? The above line only making not much help to me personally.